# is it good idea to check hour in following way?

Tags: android, android-service

I want to make service which will check updates every 2 hours.
Is it good idea to do it in following way?

```
boolean canceled = false;
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (!canceled) {
                    int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    if (hour % 2 == 0) {
                        checkForUpdate();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Comment: It would be more battery friendly if you use the AlarmManager class to set up time broadcasts.

Comment: This will run execute only once, since Thread you create has no loop.

Comment: Use alarmmanager instead..

Comment: you can use Timer my friend.

Comment: the first : use AlarmManager
the seconde: it does not work. Thread execute your code only once, when service is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way IMO would be to use `ScheduledExecutorService` which will execute thread every 2 hours:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    checkForUpdate();
  }
}, 0, 2, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you should use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). these two are more battary-saving and flexible. All you need to do is setup the alarm and handle your intent action.